# SEO and multiple product webpages

Tags: seo

So here is a crazy example that represents a problem I have:

I have a company that makes different applications for a specific type of business.  I currently have `awesomesoftware.example/coolwidget` for each of the apps (actually, there is only 1 for now, but there will soon be more).

`Awesomesoftware.example` and coolwidget is made for the wheeliechair industry, so people searching for wheeliechairs will not search for "awesomesoftware" or "coolwidget".  They will search for "wheeliechairs" though, so I also own `wheeliechairs.example` in hopes that it gives me an edge with Google.  I also host my client's instances of coolwidget at `clientname.wheeliechairs.example`.  Finally, I have a blog that is not about awesomesoftware, or coolwidget, or even wheeliechairs... but its a blog that is relevant to people who own wheeliechairs businesses that need coolwidget, so the blog is intended to bring leads and links to awesomesoftware so they can sell them coolwidget.

So how should I organize this to get the most SEO?

Currently `wheeliechair.example` has a 301 redirect to ``` awesomesoftware.example/coolwidget``, and the blog is hosted at ```blog.wheeliechair.example`with links to`awesomesoftware.example/coolwidget`.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the right idea, although is it not a bit odd that if I find a product at `awesomesoftware.example/coolwidget` and sign up that I then access it from `myName.wheeliechairs.example`

Would it not be better to keep awesomesoftware as your corporate head quarters then set up something like...

- `demo.wheeliechairs.example/widget1`
- `demo.wheeliechairs.example/widget2`
- `customer1.wheelechairs.example/widget1`
- ...
- ...

As `wheeliechairs.example` is your domain it makes sense that this is the domain name.

The blog sounds like it should have its own domain name (and on a different server for better SEO).

I would remove the 301 redirect, no one likes to be thrown about the place.

Comment: So you would say move the signup website from awesomesoftware/coolwidget to just wheeliechairs.net?  I think that makes sense.  Any reason why the blog on its own domain makes for better seo?

Comment: Because it is not directly linked to your other two products it will only water down links in and key word density across the domain.  Having it on it's own server is better still because then links across will be treated more like 'votes' as opposed to sites owned by the same person linking to each other.